# Посчитать значения с условием like SUM

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть 2 таблицы

MAs:
id,
user_id,
description_id,
count,
date

MADescriptions
id,
action

Мне надо посчитать кол-во людей(user_id) и сумму(count) за определенный период (date), сгруппировав по действиям (action)

действий много

spent_1 spent_2 ... spent_n

got_1 got_2 ... got_n

buy_1 buy_2 ... buy_n

Сейчас я считаю кол-во записей, а у меня есть поле count и мне нужно посчитать count по дням при условии где определенный MADescriptions.action

Есть ли возможность в таком запросе

```
SELECT MAs.date
     , count(DISTINCT (MAs.user_id)) AS users

     , sum(MADescriptions.action LIKE 'spent%') AS spent
     , sum(MADescriptions.action LIKE 'got%') AS got
     , sum(MADescriptions.action LIKE 'bought%') AS bought

FROM
  MAs
JOIN
  MADescriptions
ON
MAs.description_id = MADescriptions.id
WHERE
  MAs.date BETWEEN '2018-10-08' AND '2018-10-15'
  Group by  MAs.date
```

сделать нечто подобное

```
sum(MAs.count where MADescriptions.action LIKE 'spent%') AS spent
sum(MAs.count where MADescriptions.action LIKE 'got%') AS got
sum(MAs.count where MADescriptions.action LIKE 'bough%') AS bough
```

Comment: А что именно это должно означать ? количество чего вы хотите сложить ?

Comment: @Mike, сейчас я считаю кол-во записей, а у меня есть поле count и мне нужно посчитать count по дням при условии где определенный MADescriptions.action

Comment: ну чисто технически вы именно это сейчас и считаете с помощью своих sum(). правда count у вас считает уникальных пользователей, а sum считают все совпадения. Опять возвращаемся к вопросу "что вы хотите посчитать". Подозреваю, что уникальных пользователей, имеющих нужную фразу. Если у одного пользователя есть записи и spent и got, то его надо засчитать в оба счетчика ? Если да, то надо сделать выборку user_id и description с group by по этим двум полям. А уже это обернуть в ваш первый запрос.

Comment: Немного не так,я добавил структуры базы в вопрос

Comment: Ага, вот теперь стало понятней что такое count. `sum(case when MADescriptions.action LIKE 'spent%' then MAS.count else 0 end)`

Comment: @Mike, Большое спасибо! Вы очень сильно помогли!